# How can I create a draggable table in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table whose columns indicate a property of data items. Each item is then placed into its appropriate column, meaning some columns might be empty, and certainly the columns do not all contain the same number of elements (or rather, the last `n` elements in each column are empty, apart from the column that has the most elements).

Anyway, I'd like to provide a way for users to drag data items from one column to another. I'm guessing that this can be done in jquery. I've never used jquery, but have done some searching both on Google and on jquery.com, and haven't been able to find anything that does what I'm looking for.

Do I just need to use a normal HTML table and make its cells draggable? Or is there something in JQuery (or a plugin) that does what I'm looking for?

Edit: Macka's response is helpful, but doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. Is there something that allows moving a single cell in a table from one column to another? Should I be able to do that just using the jQuery UI Draggable plugin? If so, I can't figure out how at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [jQuery UI Draggables](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggables) and [this article](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/).

Comment: @Macka Seconded. The upcoming release of jquery-ui 1.6 is very slick.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a certain amount of sense. So presumably I need to implement the functionality of shifting an item from one column to another myself? I don't think the "Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin" does what I need. And presumably also I need to make each cell in the table draggable?